# How to install Oauth2.0 for python in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

Hi I have ownloaded simplegeo-python-oauth2-debian-1.5.211-0-ga83f4a2.tar.gz .I do not know how to install it for python in ubuntu. can anyone help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Extract it and run:

```
python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: Um getting this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named setuptools

Comment: Compile this the same way and try again: http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11.tar.gz#md5=7df2a529a074f613b509fb44feefe74e

Comment: It seems you need to install `python-setuptools` package.

Comment: So to do the outh2 installation the steps are { 1.sudo apt-get install python-setuptools 2.python seup.py 3.sudo python setup.py install}

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have python setup tools you will need the command below

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

Then ,just build the setup in your python environment

```
$ python setup.py build
```

When you are done, Install.

```
$ sudo python setup.py install
```